# jQuery click outside to close a filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Side Filter, where a User can fill out some information and filter a Webpage.

I want this menu to appear when clicking a button and disappear when I click outside of it. This is what I currently have to make the Filter disappear once the user clicks outside of it:

```
$(window).click(function(e) {
    if ((!$(e.target).hasClass("filterOverlay")) && (!$(e.target).hasClass("toggleFilterButton"))) {

        $('.filterOverlay').hide();
        $('.darkBackground').hide();
    }
});
```

This works. However only if the Filter is empty. Because the fun thing is, when I add an Input-Field and click it. Of course Jquery doesn't recognize it as being the Filter and closes it.

What's the best way to go with such a thing? All I find is the solution above, but as pointed out, this doesn't really fit.

Comment: can you provide your html?

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery [blur()](https://api.jquery.com/blur/) Method  for when clicking outside of an input.

> The blur event occurs when an element loses focus.

**CSS**

```
.filter-div {
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="toggleFilter">Filter</button>

<div class="filter-div">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filter" placeholder="Filter">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#toggleFilter').on('click', function() {
    $('.filter-div').slideToggle();
    if ($('.filter-div').css('display') != 'none') {
        $('#filter').focus();
    }
});

$('#filter').on('blur', function() {
    $('.filter-div').slideToggle();
});
```

Check it out:
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ypwc7Lau/13/)